# How to use Constructors in Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB. Below code should depict "Milan" in the Label on Button click. However, the string "Milan" gets depicted when I run the app, i.e., even without selecting the Button. Please suggest. Appreciate help.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim c1 As Form1 = New Form1()
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        Dim loctn As String
        InitializeComponent()
        loctn = "Milan"
        Label1.Text = loctn
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your Sub New() (the constructor), is setting the Label's Text. `Dim c1 As Form1 = New Form1()` does nothing: you create a new instance (a new *object*) of your current Form (`Form1`), but you don't use it. If you want to change the `Label.Text` property in your Button click, just set `Label1.Text = "Milan"` and remove that line from the constructor.

Comment: You must not create a new instance of the Form to set the property of one of its child controls. Note: **new instance** (new object -> *another*, distinct, object).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a student, I am new to constructors in win forms, hence my requirement of selecting the Button to depict the string (utilizing a constructor). How do I do it ?

Comment: You don't call the constructor of a class from a Button click. The constructor (as the term implies) is called when a new object is created. You don't *call it*, it's not a method. In a Button.Click handler, you can set the Label.Text to something else. If you don't want the Label.Text set when the Form is created, remove that line from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

"Make everything as simple as possible (but no simpler)"

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = "Milan"
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please make sure to name your controls better; after you've dropped the control on the form, right click it, choose properties and change the Name in the property grid. For example `Label1` might have been better called `cityLabel`. Your code will get quite confusing by the time you've got 20 labels, 20 textboxes, 5 buttons etc.. and worse you might end up posting that code and we won't be able to understand it (so it will be a challenge for your supervisor too)

Comment: I remember the initialization of form components already takes place on the designer code of the form at startup. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, though hopefully DA GAMER GURL isn't complaining that the label text is already set because they've used the Wndows Forms designer to set the label text to Milan! :)